# Concurrent ALAssetsLibrary iteration deadlock when trying to access metadata

Tags: ios, objective-c, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, alassetslibrary

When trying to iterate over image assets I though it could be an interesting idea to parallelize the access to metadata as its quite time consuming. The result was multiple thread in some kind of a deadlock. Code:

```
[_assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupLibrary usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

    if (group) {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                if (asset) {
                    NSLog(@"%d", index);
                    id s = asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata; // <----- This is the troublemaker
                }
            });
        }];
    }
} failureBlock:nil];
```

Some of the tasks complete but others are stuck. When I paused execution and inspected the thread I found that `[ALAssetRepresentation metadata]` is waiting for some semaphore signal on multiple threads.

Other times (when I remove the `NSLog`) all tasks are stuck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's gone out of scope. The main culprit I would assume is the assets library itself going out of scope in between.

Comment: `_assetsLibrary` is a member and the class instance hasn't gone out of scope.